# React Native - numberOfLines in nested Text but ignore last element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a text element looks like this:

```
<Text
  numberOfLines={2}
>
  <Text>
    {item.title}
  </Text>
  <Text>
      [more]
  </Text>
</Text>
```

What I want to achieve is when the text is longer than 2 lines, the tails for first child will appear but will keep the second child,

```
Example Example Example Example Example Example Example
Example Example Example Example Example Examp... [more]
```

Is it possible to done in React Native?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/expo/react-native-read-more-text) could help

Comment: This is good as a temporary solution but not exactly the effect I wish to achieve, since it move the "more" text to next line.